# WebDriver Ruby Custom FirefoxProfile

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox

I have a Firefox profile that I'd like to launch for testing. It's currently the only profile loaded up on my test machine's copy of Firefox. When I load WebDriver Remote it's not loading my profile. First I tried this:

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => "myprofile")
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
```

That didn't work and opened up a browser with a blank profile. Then I remember that in PHP WebDriver there was a requirement to copy the profile and Base64 encode it. So I did that:

```
profile = File.read '/home/me/firefoxprofile.zip.b64'
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => profile)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
```

But I'm still stuck with a blank profile again. :(

I set a lot of custom preferences and extensions in my profile and would like to load it for each test.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried adding -FirefoxProfilePath with the webdriver.jar and that also failed to load my profile.

**How can I load my custom Firefox profile in WebDriver Remote for testing?**